# Dynamic web scraping in Python using BeautifulSoup and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I created a web scraper that pulls data from a single web page using Python. However, I'm having trouble creating a loop that iterates until all records have been scraped while being careful to not duplicate records.

It is clear that the only changing piece of the URL is the "start=" portion.

What is the easiest way to go about adding a dynamic loop without overcomplicating?

URL page 1:

> https://www.winebusiness.com/classifieds/grapesbulkwine/?sort_type=1&sort_order=desc&start=1#anchor1

URL Page 2:

> https://www.winebusiness.com/classifieds/grapesbulkwine/?sort_type=1&sort_order=desc&start=51#anchor1

Final Page URL:

> https://www.winebusiness.com/classifieds/grapesbulkwine/?sort_type=1&sort_order=desc&start=751#anchor1

```
#Imports
import pandas as pd
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date 

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

#Set URL
URL = "https://www.winebusiness.com/classifieds/grapesbulkwine/?sort_type=1&sort_order=desc&start=1#anchor1"
res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

#Define specific table
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table wb-cl-table"})
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

#Add Listing_ID's
tbody = table.find("tbody")
df['Listing_ID'] = [np.where(tag.has_attr('href'),tag.get('href'),"no link") for tag in tbody.find_all('a')]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code on the assumption that each page is fixed at 50 lines. `for i in range(1,752,50):` loops from 1 line to 751 lines in 50-line increments.

```
#Imports
import pandas as pd
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date 

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

# Empty Dataframe create
all_data = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=['Varietal','Type','Appellation','Qty','Price','Date','Listing_ID'])

# last record[...,701,751,782] and range(1,50*n+2,50)
last = 782
lst = [x if x <= last else last for x in range(1,802,50)] 

for i in lst:
    #Set URL
    URL = "https://www.winebusiness.com/classifieds/grapesbulkwine/?sort_type=1&sort_order=desc&start={}#anchor1".format(i)
    print(URL)
    res = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

    #Define specific table
    table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table wb-cl-table"})
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

    #Add Listing_ID's
    tbody = table.find("tbody")
    df['Listing_ID'] = [np.where(tag.has_attr('href'),tag.get('href'),"no link") for tag in tbody.find_all('a')]
    all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. One question though: if the records tomorrow were to be 1,000 wouldn't this exclude anything above 751?

Comment: In that case, you need to modify `range(1,72,50)`. I'll fix the code.

Comment: If it doesn't fit in multiples of 50 as mentioned in the comments, I set the last page and put it in the list. It should be multiplied by 50 to contain the maximum page at that time.